# How can I replace a block of whitespace with nothing in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string that looks like this where the "-" are representing blocks of whitespace or just a newline (it is random on whether it is a number of spaces then a newline or just a newline):

> "Hello my name is
>      Robert and I am trying to figure
>      -
>      -
>      -
>
> out this code
>      Thanks"

All I really want to do is get rid of all the spaces/newlines between "figure" and "out" the other spaces I would want to keep them the same way if I could. The end string I would want would look like this:

> "Hello my name is
>      Robert and I am trying to figure
>      out this code
>      Thanks"

Is there an easy way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `str.split` splits on whitespace by default, so does `" ".join(s.split())` work for you?

Comment: Use regular expressions: `import re; re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', 'Hello my name is Robert and I am trying to figure     \n\n   out this code.\nThanks')`

Comment: You may also do `str.replace('\n\n', '')` which remove empty lines from the string

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri better using regex `re.sub(r'\n{2,}', ' ', str)`

Comment: Sorry everyone I had to edit the post because it wasn't formatting for me correctly. I will try all of these real quick and see how they work out.

Comment: @UrielEli Your method has worked for me thank you! It gets rid of the unwanted newlines but keeps everything else formatted the way it was before which is what I wanted. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

One way to accomplish this would be with regular expressions, which will simply allow us to find *runs* of spaces and newlines. The following code should work for your purposes:

```
import re
string = 'lorem ipsum dolor\n\n sic\n\n\n lorem'
string = re.sub(r' +', ' ', string)
string = re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', string)
```

This will replace all runs of spaces with a single space, and all runs of newlines with a single newline.